# OpenFileMapping is returning different handle then returned by CreateFileMapping

Tags: windows, winapi

When I am using `OpenFileMapping` from a child process with same name as used in parent process for `CreateFileMapping`, it returns different handle (this seems okay).
Now if I use `MapViewOfFileEx` on handle returned by `OpenFileMapping`, it gives different address then the parent process.

However when I use both these function in different process as described on below link, it works fine (returns same value of handle):
[Creating Named Shared Memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Do I need to care anything extra for using `CreateFileMapping` and `OpenFileMapping` when using in parent,child processes?

Comment: This is entirely normal.

Comment: It seems for parent child communication we need to reserve memory space for child before it can map to it, else if child process has used that address for something else it will result into above behavior. My question is can it happen for 2 different processes the memory map created in first process is not accessible to second?

Comment: It is technically possible if a process has used up all 2 gigabyte of virtual memory.  You'll have much bigger problems by then.  Otherwise trivially solved by building a 64-bit program.

Comment: Do you know the reason why it behaves differently for parent-child communication?

Comment: Nothing is "different", everything you quoted is *entirely normal*.

Comment: If the handles in two different processes have the same numerical value, that's only by coincidence.  There's no reason they should.  Similarly, there's no reason for them to map the view of the shared memory at the same address, which is why you don't need to reserve memory space for the child mapping ahead of time.

Comment: (The most likely reason that the child process looks "different" to the separately launched process is that the child process is inheriting handles from the parent.  That means some of the handle numbers are already used.  But it doesn't matter at all what the handle values are, or at what address the view is mapped.)

Comment: all above explanation is right and I got my problem, it was due to size of memory mapped view, as Windows doesn't have exact API, so it was failing due to that in generic code which had led me to think above.

Comment: now the other point in this regard is that what happen if 2 processes having handles (one by CreateFileMapping and other by OpenFileMapping) and memory addresses (by using MapViewOfFile) crashes. How to clear the file mapping, let us assume I have 3rd process which knows only about the name of filemapping object, can I clear using name something like shm_unlink()? Or does it automatically disappear when referencing object crash?

Comment: You can even map the same piece of memory twice in the same process. In this case MapViewOfFile(Ex) will of course return two different addresses although the same handle has been passed to the function.

Comment: okay, but what I really wanted to know is whether the handle gets automatically closed if a process which opens it, exits without closing it?